# Jade Minified Javascript not parsed as block of text

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a minified app.min.js file which is ~ 80Kb big and contains all javascript code my website requires. If I include this file as script with source pointing to app.min.js everything works fine, no JS errors. But if I try to make a new .jade file and place all javascript code inside so that I can do include javascript.jade I get an error on first line of code which I dont understand why? I also tried using script. instead of just script but I still get an error ( wtf? ) Isnt using script. supposed to force Jade to interpret that as a text block?

How am I supposed to debug this error if all my code (80Kb) of it is in one line? And yes I have tried splitting the code into multiple lines and I get the same error. Yes I have verified everything and I'm not missing space before a line, yet I still get this error..

If someone wants to try here a link to my jade file ( it is an exact copy of my app.min.js except I added script. above it just as Jade needs..)  :  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=F3AqQQL2 Note : please copy paste the file into text editor because Chrome doesnt show spaces in lines.

Warning: missing space before text for line 1 of jade file       "/var/www/views/app_js.jade"

Warning: missing space before text for line 1 of jade file "/var/www/views/app_js.jade"

Warning: missing space before text for line 1 of jade file "/var/www/views/app_js.jade"

Warning: missing space before text for line 1 of jade file "/var/www/views/app_js.jade"

Warning: missing space before text for line 1 of jade file "/var/www/views/app_js.jade"

Warning: missing space before text for line 1 of jade file "/var/www/views/app_js.jade"

{ [Error: /var/www/views/app_js.jade:2
   1| script.
   2|   if(!function............

The error I'm getting is : 'Unexpected text ^]'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code breaks parsing. You can solve this problem by passing the code through `!{}`. That allows to include text without parsing:

```
// app.js
res.render("index.jade", {
     code: fs.readFileSync('your-script.js')
});

// jade
script.
    !{code}
```

Comment: Might also want to try the `script` then `include your-script.js`. Though, if it's breaking parsing, it may not make a difference. Though in this case, it probably won't try to parse it.